# Receiving raw ethernet packets - timing issues

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, networking

I have a scenario where I construct and send a raw ethernet packet to a bespoke hardware device. The packet triggers a response packet to be sent back by the device.

My code performs a `sendto()` call to transmit the outgoing packet and after that a `recvfrom()` call to try and receive the response. The `recvfrom()` is in a while loop such that it keeps trying to receive a packet until `recvfrom()` indicates its received > 0 bytes.

I've run Wireshark to confirm that my outgoing packet is constructed correctly and sent, I can also see the response packet from the device and it is correctly formed.

What I can't do is receive it with my `recvfrom()` call. The while loop effectively hangs as `recvfrom()` never returns a value other than 0.

I'm thinking that maybe I need the `recvfrom()` call in a separate 'listener' thread that is running prior to the `sendto()` call. Currently my application isn't threaded. I just run the `recvfrom()` after the `sendto()`.

Is it possible that I am simply missing the packet with my non-threaded approach, or are packets buffered in some way such that they can be received even if they are sent before a corresponding `recvfrom()` is executed?

I would be very interested to know if there is a defacto way of doing this sort of thing. It would be great not to have to make my app multithreaded, but I can if need be.

Comment: have you confirmed you listen on the right ethernet interface? and have you ever had success with this method?

Comment: what's the content of those raw ethernet packages? some well-known protocol like IP or something completely custom? In the latter case, I wouldn't be surprised if some "firewall" (packet filter) eliminates the inbound package.

Comment: content is the header containing the dest and src MAC address and the payload length - then the actual payload. If there was a packet filter I'm not sure I could have seen the response packet with wireshark running on the host machine?

Comment: when you say ethernet interface, do you mean in terms of an arg to the socket() call, in this case i'm using AF_PACKET as the protocol family

Comment: the device sends its response to a MAC address of 0x222222 - I'm wondering whether somehow I have to set the host to promiscuous mode and filter on that MAC addr, but I can't see how you do that programatically within the C code?

Comment: one thing that is consistent between the sendto() and the recvfrom() calls is the int socket addr used - is that enough to receive the response packet though?

Comment: this looks hopeful -> https://gist.github.com/austinmarton/2862515

Comment: accompanying blog post -> https://austinmarton.wordpress.com/2011/09/14/sending-raw-ethernet-packets-from-a-specific-interface-in-c-on-linux/

Comment: If the response is going to the `0x222222` MAC address, and that is not the address of your receiving host, then you will never see the response. The response needs to be sent to the MAC address of the host want to receive it. Your NIC will ignore frames received that are not destined to its MAC address, and on switched ethernet, the frame will never even be delivered to the switch interface where your host is connected.

Comment: I'm not sure thats correct (if it is then I'm in big trouble). I think you can set the host to run in promiscuous mode to receive *all* packets, then filter in software to look for MAC 0x222222 - will report back as/when I have any success in achieving this..

Comment: yep - you are incorrect. I've just successfully received a raw ethernet packet with dest MAC 0x222222 which has nothing to do with the MAC of my NIC. I broadly used the approach from the links in the comments above.

Comment: bear in mind though that i'm talking about raw ethernet packets here with an ethernet cable going direct from the host (laptop) to the bespoke device - there are no switches involved. You're prob right that this wouldn't work over a normal network containing switches..

Comment: in other words this is quite a bespoke use of point to point ethernet down below the tcp/ip layer

Comment: Could you please add the code to your question? It's tremendously hard to discuss something unseen.